# Why won't valueless states appear when making ggplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to plot a map of the US states based on the frequency of certain businesses I have parsed into R.

What happens when I plot is that the generated map just shows me the states where there are businesses (only about 15), therefore not showing the rest of the states.

Here is my code:

```
aux <- latlong2state(data.frame(x=allDataBusiness$longitude,y=allDataBusiness$latitude))
allDataBusiness["region"] <- NA
allDataBusiness$region <- aux

all_states <- map_data("state")
temp<-as.data.frame(table(aux))
colnames(temp)<- c("region", "count")


p <- ggplot(temp, aes(map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(aes(fill = count), map = all_states, color ="black") +
  expand_limits(x = all_states$long, y = all_states$lat) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text =  element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="darkred") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 20, barheight = .5)) + 
  ggtitle("Busines Frequency Choropleth")
```

`allDataBusiness` has 3 columns(longitude, latitude and it´s id). I create one more column where i put the region associated with the respective coordinate.

After that I create a DF to put the frequency of the number of times these states appear then I plot the data.

Image I am generating in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUGrI.jpg).

I know that it must be something so basic but I'm just going around in circles in here.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the output of [AllDataBusiness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT3TK.png)

```
allBusinessData <- 
structure(list(latitude = c(34.13729, 32.89915, 49.41999, 49.42169, 
49.11919, 39.28675, 39.28679, 39.95398, 34.96329, 42.43932, 47.66441, 
34.99269, 42.44433, 32.87958, 29.71918, 47.65743, 37.86849, 32.87974, 
39.95299, 42.38919, 37.43942, 37.43924, 34.19189, 42.72999, 29.79988, 
42.73461, 41.82826, 42.37319, 49.45195, 39.95469, 42.27551, 49.11629
), longitude = c(-118.13299, -117.24295, -86.89949, -86.99516, 
-88.23939, -97.73632, -97.74489, -75.19538, -118.44193, -76.49249, 
-122.39151, -117.79999, -76.51255, -117.23223, -95.49158, -122.31321, 
-122.26199, -117.23613, -75.19229, -72.51929, -122.16229, -122.17419, 
-117.71499, -73.69159, -95.49298, -73.68918, -71.49929, -71.11769, 
-79.93327, -75.29999, -83.73795, -88.22139), region = structure(c(1L, 
6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
2L), .Label = c("california", "illinois", "indiana", "massachusetts", 
"michigan", "NA", "new york", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", 
"texas", "washington"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("latitude", 
"longitude", "region"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Post output of `dput(allDataBusiness)`.

Comment: @BondedDust output is enormous and `dput` would only show the last columns (the regions). I instead added the `View(allDataBusiness)` on my question. Or do you really want `dput`to check my data structure? Thanks mate.

Comment: How about a `dput(head(allDataBusiness, n=100))` then? We can't run the code w/o some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to plot a base `geom_map` with `all_states` first, then overlay your filled ones (there is an alternative where you just fill in the "missing" states in the `temp` data frame)

```
p <- ggplot(all_states, aes(map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(fill="white", map=all_states, color="black") +
  geom_map(data=temp, aes(fill = count), map = all_states, color ="black") +
  expand_limits(x = all_states$long, y = all_states$lat) +
  coord_map(projection="mercator") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text =  element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="darkred") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 20, barheight = .5)) + 
  ggtitle("Busines Frequency Choropleth")
p
```

[image]

I threw in a `coord_map` to help make it easier to resize and keep proprotions.

Comment: @hrbmstr First of all thanks for the answer! And I did used `geo_map` before posting in here, and should've said that, but what happened is that when I used `geo-map´, it would fill the empty borders just like your but would also scr*w some border..like it would create imaginary lines over the map.

Comment: Well, I thought it was useful, even if Vitz has declined to either upvote or accept.

Comment: @hrbmstr and BondedDust Sorry guys, I can't upvote yet, I'm a recent user. Yes the question is answered and will upvote the answer in the future :D. Thanks again both of you.

Comment: I tend to avoid `geom_map` these days, but it works really well if you can code around the quirks. Have you looked at the `choroplethr` package? Some truly cool stuff there for US choropleths.